# Private LAN on a separate network adapater

Tags: networking, windows-10, lan, private-network

I would like to control a series of TCP/IP enabled devices from my computer.  I'd like to create a private network so that the devices are only accessible from my computer.  Ideally this private network should be on its own network adapter, separate to any other network adapters in my computer.

So, I've bought a PCI-e network adapter and installed into my Windows computer.  Connected to this I have an 8 port desktop switch.

How do I go about setting up a new, private network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a seperate adapter on your machine you will need to ensure that it has an address on the interface, If the PCI-e adapter has installed fully and is operational and can be seen from within network and sharing center.

1. Assign IP address via DHCP or static if no server available for DHCP
2. Ensure that all other devices in your private network are in the same IP range
3. If you have any networks that are not directly connected to the adapter you will likely need to add routes.

Assuming the rest of your private network is ready and waiting it should just be a case of assigning an address and away you go. If you need to assign an address you will need to select an ip range that will not overlap with your primary connection i.e if your primary connection uses 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 you should ensure that your private network uses something different such as 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0

You may need to provide more information if you have specific requirements

Comment: Many thanks for your response.  That all makes sense to me.

The idea of having a separate adapter is to allow our customers to use the 'standard' adapter for their own network access, and then use the separate adapter to control our custom hardware via TCP/IP.

Just had a thought.  Without knowing in advance our customer's network's primary IP range we could potentially cause a conflict if the static address of the separate adapter overlaps with theirs.

Comment: If i have understood correctly you could in theory make it so that when a "customer" was connected to the machine that it disables that particular network adapter via GPO but when you log in the adapter is re-enabled allowing you to access the resource. However, you may struggle to segregate access if you are wanting to have both yourself and the customer connected simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

By default windows won't route packets between subnets, so you simply need to setup the adaptor (and the connected devices for it) with a different subnet than the one you're using in your current network.